# GhostScript not running in 64bit OS

Tags: c#, cmd, ghostscript

The below C# code I am able to run in Windows 7 32bit OS but it won't run in Windows 7 64bit OS. Even I used alternative working directory for each but I don't know why it's not generating TIFF file.

Note: If I use direct command prompt its working fine. But in C sharp it not working.

```
       System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.14\bin";

        //startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.14\bin"; 

        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";

        startInfo.Arguments = "/c gswin32c -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sCompression=lzw -r300x300  -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=D:\\Test\\Project%04d.tiff E:\\21062014\\MedSoft\\MedSoft\\bin\\Debug\\Output\\02_Combined.pdf";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Comment: how can it work in 32-bit windows if `C:\Program Files (x86)` isn't exist there? And what's your project target settings, 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: no i actually changed the working directory. You can see the code i just commented used x86 for 64bit os. My target settings is 32bit

Comment: You don't need separate lines for 32 and 64-bit windows. Try `"%ProgramFiles%\gs\gs9.14\bin"`, it'll always return the 32-bit program files folder. Or `%ProgramW6432%` to return the default program files folder depending on 32 or 64 bit windows. Don't hardcode them

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Ghostscript wrapper for **.NET**.

You can find one here: [**Ghostscript.NET on GitHub**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET)

Usage example can be found here: [**Ghostscript Processor C# Sample**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/ProcessorSample.cs)